# Convert cardinal abbreviations into full cardinal direction

Tags: beginner, ruby, converting

I'm still learning Ruby and I made the following function to convert `"N"` or `"SE"` into `"NORTH"` or `"SOUTH EAST"` respectively.  The function works and the tests all pass, but the code seems to be overly complicated.  Any suggestions on how to clean it up and make it more Ruby-ish?

### Code

```
module Example 
  class Utils
    CARDINAL_PATTERN = /^([NS]?)([EW]?)$/
    CARDINAL_DB = {'N'=>'NORTH', 'S'=>'SOUTH', 'E'=>'EAST', 'W'=>'WEST' }
    def correct_cardinal word
      clean_word = word.gsub(/\p{Punct}/, '').upcase
      match = CARDINAL_PATTERN.match(clean_word)
      if match
        if (not match[1].empty?) and (not match[2].empty?)
          CARDINAL_DB[match[1]] + " " + CARDINAL_DB[match[2]]
        elsif (not match[1].empty?)
          CARDINAL_DB[match[1]]
        elsif (not match[2].empty?)
          CARDINAL_DB[match[2]]
        else
          ""
        end
      else
        word
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

### Tests

```
describe Example::Utils do
  let(:utils) { Example::Utils.new}

  describe '#correct_cardinal' do
    it 'should correct S' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('S')).to eq "SOUTH"
    end 

    it 'should correct N' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('N')).to eq "NORTH"
    end 

    it 'should correct E' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('E')).to eq "EAST"
    end 

    it 'should correct W' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('W')).to eq "WEST"
    end 

    it 'should strip single period' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('W.')).to eq "WEST"
    end 

    it 'should correct SE' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('SE')).to eq "SOUTH EAST"
    end 

    it 'should correct SW' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('SW')).to eq "SOUTH WEST"
    end 

    it 'should correct NE' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('NE')).to eq "NORTH EAST"
    end 

    it 'should correct NW' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('NW')).to eq "NORTH WEST"
    end 

    it 'should strip multiple periods' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('N.W.')).to eq "NORTH WEST"
    end 

    it 'should not correct 1' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('1')).to eq "1"
    end 

    it 'should not ordinalize eggs' do
      expect(utils.correct_cardinal('EGGS')).to eq "EGGS"
    end 

  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- I'd leave some room between the constants and the method definitions (subjective).
- `if (not match[1].empty?) and (not match[2].empty?)`. Parenthenses not necessary. In any case, for boolean operations, use `!`, `&&`, `||`.
- When you have so many similar `if`s, they can usually be refactored into something else (usually, with no conditionals at all, but array processing).

First, with your code as reference mind, I'd write:

```
module Example 
  class Utils
    CARDINAL_PATTERN = /^([NS]?)([EW]?)$/
    CARDINAL_DB = {'N' => 'NORTH', 'S' => 'SOUTH', 'E' => 'EAST', 'W' => 'WEST'}

    def correct_cardinal(word)
      clean_word = word.gsub(/\p{Punct}/, '').upcase
      match = CARDINAL_PATTERN.match(clean_word)
      if match
        cardinals = match.captures.reject(&:empty?)
        CARDINAL_DB.values_at(*cardinals).join(" ")
      else
        word
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

On a second refactor, as @janos pointed out, you can build the complete hash of {CARDINALS => NAME} (well, it's so short you could just write down all its values, but let's build it programatically to see a way to do it).

```
module Example 
  class Utils
    CARDINALS = {'N' => 'NORTH', 'S' => 'SOUTH', 'E' => 'EAST', 'W' => 'WEST'} 
    # DIRECTIONS: {"NE"=>"NORTH EAST", "NW"=>"NORTH WEST", "N"=>"NORTH", ...}
    DIRECTIONS = ["N", "S", ""].product(["E", "W", ""]).map do |cardinals|
      name = CARDINALS.values_at(*cardinals).compact.join(" ")
      [cardinals.join, name]
    end.to_h

    def correct_cardinal(word)
      clean_word = word.gsub(/\p{Punct}/, '').upcase
      DIRECTIONS.fetch(clean_word, word)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The first option is something closer to that I wanted to do, but wasn't familiar enough with the ruby APIs.

Answer (score 3):

All the round brackets are unnecessary here:

```
if (not match[1].empty?) and (not match[2].empty?)
  CARDINAL_DB[match[1]] + " " + CARDINAL_DB[match[2]]
elsif (not match[1].empty?)
  CARDINAL_DB[match[1]]
elsif (not match[2].empty?)
  CARDINAL_DB[match[2]]
```

Another solution can be pre-populating `CARDINAL_DB` with all the possible values:

```
CARDINAL_DB = {'N'=>'NORTH', 'S'=>'SOUTH', 'E'=>'EAST', 'W'=>'WEST' }
['N', 'S'].each { |ns|
    ['E', 'W'].each { |ew|
        CARDINAL_DB[ns + ew] = CARDINAL_DB[ns] + ' ' + CARDINAL_DB[ew]
    }
}
```

This will simplify the `correct_cardinal` method a bit:

```
def correct_cardinal word
  clean_word = word.gsub(/\p{Punct}/, '').upcase
  match = CARDINAL_PATTERN.match(clean_word)
  if match
      CARDINAL_DB[match[1] + match[2]]
  else
      word
  end
end
```